# passing from one lightbox to another?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Currently I am working on lightbox in which i want to transfer the list present from one lightbox to another. When i clicked on any one element of that list it must go to other lightbox having same url and id parameter as in 1st lightbox list element.

Please help 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

Use jquery with [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

`jQuery(this).appendTo('#myotherlist');`

Or in normal JS using [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/appendchild):

`document.getElementById('myotherlist').appendChild(this)`

either way you use, the line would go in an `onclick` event.

Note: this is untested and written from memory.